# Get data from website

Tags: excel, vba

```
<span itemprop="streetAddress">

    **94 Grand St**

</span>
```

how to get this data through getelementby method in excel vba

I have tried getelementbyid, getelementbyname etc. but nothing is working

```
Option Explicit

Sub find()
'Uses late binding, or add reference to Microsoft HTML Object Library
'  and change variable Types to use intellisense
Dim ie As Object 'InternetExplorer.Application
Dim html As Object 'HTMLDocument
Dim Listings As Object 'IHTMLElementCollection
Dim l As Object 'IHTMLElement
Dim r As Long
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With ie
        .Visible = False
        .Navigate "http://www.yelp.com/biz/if-boutique-new-york#query:boutique"
        ' Don't show window
        'Wait until IE is done loading page
        Do While .readyState <> 4
            Application.StatusBar = "Downloading information, Please wait..."
            DoEvents
        Loop
        Set html = .Document
    End With
    Set Listings = html.getElementsByTagName("span") ' ## returns the list
    MsgBox (Listings(0))
    For Each l In Listings
        '## make sure this list item looks like the listings Div Class:
        '   then, build the string to put in your cell
        Range("A1").Offset(r, 0).Value = l.innerText
            r = r + 1
    Next

Set html = Nothing
Set ie = Nothing
End Sub
```

The above program is used by me to get the innerText value inside the span tag... but its not working

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: What does it do instead of working?  Your getElementsByTagName look ok, so what happens when you run this?

Comment: Have u debugged ur code .. where u r getting error ?

Comment: Did you accept the answer on the previous question which is nearly identical? I notice you did not use the proper `If/Then` logic to check the `l.innerText`, as I previously suggested. Without looking at the specifics of this question, since it seems so similar to your previous one, BrettDJ's answer below looks good, but as a matter of etiquette, since you've used nearly *all* the code I provided you earlier, an upvote or acceptance of that answer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For the single result you are looking for in detail you want to use these two lines in your code (there is only 1 listing at the detailed level)

**Adapt your IE code**

```
  Set Listings = html.getElementbyid("bizInfoBody") ' ## returns the list
  Range("A1").Offset(r, 0).Value = Listings.innerText
```

**with XMLHTTP**

```
Sub GetTxt()
Dim objXmlHTTP As Object
Dim objHtmlDoc As Object
Dim objHtmlBody As Object
Dim objTbl As Object

Dim strResponse As String
Dim strSite As String


Set objHtmlDoc = CreateObject("htmlfile")
Set objHtmlBody = objHtmlDoc.body

Set objXmlHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
strSite = "http://www.yelp.com/biz/if-boutique-new-york"

With objXmlHTTP
    .Open "GET", strSite, False
    .Send
    If .Status = 200 Then
    strResponse = .responseText
    objHtmlBody.innerHTML = objXmlHTTP.responseText
    Set objTbl = objHtmlBody.Document.getElementbyid("bizInfoBody")
    MsgBox objTbl.innerText
    End If
End With

End Sub
```